# Need to change the title of views

Tags: views, 7

I have created a view which displays all the posts of an author. I need to set the title as - "(Author Name)'s Posts" or "Posts by (Author Name)" where Author Name will change depending on the profile the reader is visiting. Can someone please help me with it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using **Contextual Filter** in the view then you can override the title by putting `%1` for first argument, `%2` for second argument etc..

Otherwise add a contextual filter for something like "`Content:Author`"(depend upon your need) in your created view & override the title in there by placing `%1`